# Read Access Database Row Headers using C#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

In MS Access Database - I have a column - DataType image

In these columns, using VBA there are some office documents stored (xls, xlsx, doc, docx, pdf) - I found that Access Application adds the header automatically when you save the data using VBA; 
When you opens it - it detects automatically the File Extension and opens it with its respective application like Microsoft Excel/Word/PowerPoint.

I would like to achieve the same using C#, I got this nice tools: Mime-Detective
https://github.com/Muraad/Mime-Detective

As a POC, I had uploaded using FileUpload on WinForms and there it works.
However when opening a file from the Access Database, it cannot find its extension.

May be the header on the Access Database would be different or there are more offset ?

Please help.

**EDIT**
the previous team who have developed the application using VB => MSACCESS have used OLE Object to store the content  - and it seems with header.

Now there is a requirement to migrate these content (mostly office documents), using C# this time (WinForms or Web Based Technologies), the challenge is to get the exact File Extension.

For test purpose, I have create a simple WinForm to Upload/Read the byte[] from a Test Database with same DataType using the Mime-Detective tools and it works perfectly.

Using the same code, when I read the byte[] from the Access Database this time, I cannot be read.

As you can see below the starting bytes doesn't look similar despite both are xlsx files.

I am suspecting that OLE Object would add some extra Information in the header ?

Currently for getting the FileType, the offset are set at 512 - is there any way to find the offset calculation from a byte[] object ?

```
public readonly static FileType WORDX = new FileType(new byte?[0], 512, "docx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");

public readonly static FileType EXCELX = new FileType(new byte?[0], 512, "xlsx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

public readonly static FileType WORD = new FileType(new byte?[] { 0xEC, 0xA5, 0xC1, 0x00 }, 512, "doc", "application/msword");

public readonly static FileType EXCEL = new FileType(new byte?[] { 0x09, 0x08, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x05, 0x00 }, 512, "xls", "application/excel");


Start Bytes from Access Database [xlsx]

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
Start Bytes from Test Sql Database [xlsx]

0x504B03041400060008000000210034E1EA94ED0100002B0A0000130008025B436F6E74656E745F54797065735D2E786D6C20A2040228A00002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget to ask a question!

Comment: Maybe you could explain what you are trying to do rather than *how* you are trying to do something.  Are you saying you dont know the schema of a DB you are trying to open?

Comment: In simple terms, there is a requirement to migrate Data from Ms Access to SQL, that sounds very simple isn't. The previous team who have developed the application using VB => MSACCESS have used OLE Object to store the content  - and it seems with header. http://searchwindowsserver.techtarget.com/definition/OLE-Object-Linking-and-Embedding

Comment: Please read further details on my above EDIT